# Why is a new variable which copies my static variable, changing my static variable?

Tags: c#, static, sfml

```
class Graphics

    public static Image[] ImageArray = new Image[16];
```

And in a different class,

```
        //Copy original Array
        tempArray = Graphics.ImageArray;
```

I am trying to make `tempArray` an exact copy of the static variable, which should NEVER change, but `tempArray` needs to change. Instead of copying the static variable, it seems to be adding another variable name to it.

Because if I change `tempArray`, it's as if I change `ImageArray`.
How do I simply copy `ImageArray` by making `tempArray` a non-static duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFML has its own parameter to copy an Image. Should have just checked the SFML.Image definition first.

```
      //Create Image Array and fill it
        Image[] tempArray = new Image[16];
        for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++)
        {
            tempArray[z] = new Image(Graphics.ImageArray[z]);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

> Why is a new variable which copies my static variable, changing my static variable?

Short answer is, because it does not copy your static variable. It creates a second reference to the same static variable, without making a copy. That is why changing the array through the `tempArray` variable is equivalent to changing it through the `ImageArray` variable.

> So...how do I copy it instead?

This depends on the kind of copy you need:

- If you need a "shallow" copy (i.e. the array is copied, but images inside refer to the same ones as in the static array), use `Array.Copy` method
- If you need a "deep" copy, use LINQ's `ToArray` method, and make image copies inside the `Select`.

Shallow copy:

```
tempArray = new Image[Graphics.ImageArray.Length];
Array.Copy(Graphics.ImageArray, tempArray, Graphics.ImageArray.Length);
```

Deep copy:

```
tempArray = Graphics.ImageArray.Select(img => new Image(img)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `tempArray = Graphics.ImageArray.Clone()`.

Note that `Clone()` creates a shallow copy of array, for deep copy use this: 
`tempArray = Graphics.ImageArray.Select(i => i.Clone() as Image).ToArray()`